# Typescript Omit helper not allowing overriding properties

Tags: typescript, tsc

```js
interface ContextValue {
    [K: string]: {
        value: any
        error: boolean
        errorMessage: string
    }
}

export interface GatheringExpChildMachineBaseContext<TYPE> extends Omit<ContextValue, 'id' | 'originalData' | 'order'> {
    id?: string
    originalData: TYPE
    order: number
}
```

I get the error message `TS 2411 Property 'id' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type '{ value: any; error: boolean; errorMessage: string; }'.`, and the equivalent messages for `originalData` and `order`.

This seems incorrect, as Omit should grab the keys of the `ContextValue` interface (which is any key,) and omit the union types I supplied `'id' | 'originalData' | 'order'` and allow me to override them.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript does not currently support subtraction/[negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317), which is what you'd need to say "`string` but `not ("id" | "originalData" | "order")`".  `Omit` is implemented by using the [`Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu) on the keys.  `Exclude<T, U>` filters any union members of `T` which are subtypes of `U`.  Since `string` is not a union, the filter acts on `string` as a whole.  And since `string` is not a subtype of a finite union of string literals (it's a supertype, not a subtype), the value of `Exclude<string, "id" | "originalData" | "order">` is just `string`.  In some sense, the current version of TypeScript thinks "`string` minus `("id" | "originalData" | "order")` equals `string`".

The specific functionality you're looking for, where you can make exceptions to an index signature, is the subject of an open issue in GitHub: [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867).  If you want to see this implemented in TypeScript you might want to go to that issue and give it a .  Its also marked "awaiting more feedback" so if you think you have a compelling use case for it that isn't covered already, you might want to make a comment detailing it.

For now there are only various workarounds, each of which have an associated pain point.

---

You can use an intersection to avoid the error, which makes it easy to use an existing value of that type:

```
interface Extension<T> { id?: string, originalData: T, order: number }
type GECMBCIntersection<T> = ContextValue & Extension<T>
```

Which makes it easy to use an existing value of that type:

```
declare const i: GECMBCIntersection<number>;
i.id?.toUpperCase(); // okay
i.originalData.toFixed(); // okay
i.order.toFixed(); // okay
i.somethingElse.errorMessage.toUpperCase(); // okay
```

But it's not easy to verify that a value is of that type, for the same not-compatible-with-index-signature reason:

```
const iBad: GECMBCIntersection<number> = {
    originalData: 1,
    order: 2
} // error! originalData is not assignable to index signature
```

---

You can represent it as a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) in the actual keys instead of as a concrete type with an index signature:

```
type GECMBCConstraint<K extends PropertyKey, T> =
    Record<Exclude<K, keyof Extension<any>>, ContextValue[string]> & Extension<T>;
```

But then you need to carry an extra generic type parameter everywhere and use helper functions to create instances without redundant key names:

```
const asGECMBCConstraint = <G extends GECMBCConstraint<keyof G, any>>(g: G) => g;
const cGood = asGECMBCConstraint({
    originalData: 1,
    order: 2,
    somethingElse: {
        value: "blork",
        error: true,
        errorMessage: "blork!!",
    }
})
```

And even then it's hard to work with an actual value when you want to access the erstwhile-index-signature properties:

```
function cBad<G extends GECMBCConstraint<keyof G, any>>(g: G) {
    if ("somethingElse" in g) {
        g.somethingElse; // error
    }
    const asserted = g as GECMBCIntersection<any>;
    if ("somethingElse" in asserted) {
        asserted.somethingElse.errorMessage.toUpperCase() // okay
    }

}
```

---

For now I usually recommend refactoring the code so as not to mix index signatures with other properties.  If you can do so, rewrite your type so that it *has* a `ContextValue` instead of so that it *is* a `ContextValue`. (This is also known as [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)).  Then you get the simpler interface:

```
interface Easier<T> extends Extension<T> {
    contextValues: ContextValue;
}
```

which is easy for the compiler to reason about:

```
const easy: Easier<number> = {
    originalData: 1,
    order: 2,
    contextValues: {
        somethingElse: {
            value: "blork",
            error: true,
            errorMessage: "blork!!",
        }
    }
};
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-jTEYACkpgc1GBBpOlIshptaAEqjMohPwHYjlKvpRFt9Awda1oKhKTSCIRdKlhb4cQQejWHi8KJrDYBOeTSLvVXq85g4t9UvWCvgLvIELtGubOIRq+oG+cO9gEIT6RTkW6QLku4LcJckJdlE3CnuemoIO0GhxA+l76teZzfh44KCMImLBqGRTIM6rpQOU7oei6Qi0FyPL8oKwqWFaVHyGIyysAARImyiIuxlF6PoUBKO6nCkHx-FihKZgWBxXFQIifp+rx1ouA4kK7DAxAgA8mDIAg2pxE+L4BG+RZoZ+GHlpW-6Ae0wEyKB4FFpBOF0MA07guxNG8gKthCiM7Gpsg3DOdawjcB8Xl0b5DEUgiYrKdacHILG0CQMhszcMl75mbc0DGtsIGnsIbnIB5kU+dwfkQAFoBZSMUBpSFzHCClDWkhF3LefRIoSSYUnSn8srQPKEBQj6yqosIjRUNN7hDPASDrGCwDQFMRl1jOmxHmtLm0Oqa5LKQbCsKuODrssp4uEl2hsNIrA+Mtq1mi8D67YGdohriTpibQbqsBRiXzGdh0mAIoV0OV3WMW9-HIKxEjIJxhDcUpzXiYJyisCJEA-bDvoY+KfVSjJyNyQpqOwy4U3OKe1BAA)